# Adding PHP Form Data to Existing MySQL Table via Separate Form

Tags: php, html, forms

I am looking for either guidance, or a link to a tutorial that will help me add data from a second form to the MySQL table that was only partially filled in by the first form.

I can't use one form, because I want users to submit data in the first form (user information), before they can get to the second form (numbers the user will input).  And I can't use a separate table, because I want to look at the table in phpMyAdmin after the fact, and look at what user added what numbers.  The fields already exist in the table, they just need to be filled in.

Comment: Show us what have you tried. Or guys may close your question.

Comment: So why not insert the data in the first form, and when you get to the second form, populate the input values with the data retrieved in the table?

Comment: Or pass the result of `mysql_insert_id()` to the second form, and include it in a hidden field so the second form's handler knows which record to update? In general, have you done any research or made any attempt to solve the problem at all?

Comment: I've been watching videos on PHP and I can't seem to find anything that tells me how to fill in fields in one table once you've submitted a form to fill in the table.  I was just looking for a small amount of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding, you are inserting new user information from Form 1 and then sending the user to a new page with a new form to fill out added information. Correct? ... If so, simply retrieve the ID from the table where they were inserted and use that to insert data from Form 2.

This would be done in 3 queries. On the first page, your new user will be inserted into the table with a simple insert query and then the ID of the insert will be placed in a SESSION variable:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$query = "INSERT INTO table Name, Address, Phone VALUES fullname, addr, phone1";
mysqli_query($con, $query);

$_SESSION['id'] = mysqli_insert_id($con);
```

Then on page 2, use the ID in the session variable to complete the 2nd insert query.

Comment: Thanks!  That helps immensely.  When handling the form for page 2 do I need to create a separate file to do the "action" or can I put all the php code into one file?

Comment: It sounds like Form 2 is on another page, right? You can create a single PHP file to "include" on your page and then call certain functions or set parameters as needed. The "action" on Form 2 would use the same connection to the database with a different insert query that utilizes a WHERE clause:

    INSERT INTO table_2 Info1, Info2, Info3 VALUES newinfo1, newinfo2, newinfo3 WHERE ID = $_SESSION['id']

Comment: Yes Form 2 is on another page.  I get an error when using this code, but when I comment out everything from `$_SESSION['id']` down I get the first form to work properly.  I think I have to add this code in two comments b/c of character limit

Comment: I'm having trouble entering this code.  I'll be back in a minute when I figure out how to properly add it.

Comment: $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
  
if (!$con)
     
{
      
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
     
}
 
 
mysql_select_db("php-test", $con);
 
 
$sql1="INSERT INTO jobTicketData (OperatorName, OperatorNumber, PressNumber, PartNumber, PartName, Date, Shift, MaterialColor, StandardCavity, ActiveCavity) VALUES ('$_POST[opName]','$_POST[opNum]','$_POST[pressNum]','$_POST[partNum]','$_POST[partName]','$_POST[date]','$_POST[shift]','$_POST[material]','$_POST[sCavity]','$_POST[aCavity]')";`

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't able to edit that fast enough.  You don't need to respond anymore, I'll try to find it on the internet somewhere.  Thanks for getting me started.

Answer (score 0):

For your INSERT query, your POST variables shouldn't be in quotes like that. If they are strings, simply remove the single quotes. If they are numbers intended to be entered as strings, you'll have to escape the quotes.

So instead of this:

```
VALUES ('$_POST[opName]','$_POST[opNum]', ...
```

Do this:

```
VALUES ($_POST[opName],$_POST[opNum], ...
```

Answer (score -2):

You'll want to use a MySQL UPDATE query.

Something along the lines of this is what you're probably looking for:

`UPDATE users SET favorite_number=value, lucky_number=value2,...WHERE username=johnny`